# Big O Notation in Algorithm Analysis

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

According to the book "Introduction to Algorithms" a function that has the following form
$f(n)=an+b$
belongs to $O(n^2)$, and that this can be easily proven if we set $c=a+\vert b\rvert$ and $n_0=\max(1; -b/a)$.
I did not get how $n_0$ was found, particularly $-b/a$

Comment: To prove that $an+b\in O(n^2)$ it suffices to observe that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(an+b)/n^2=\lim_{n\to \infty}(a/n+b/n^2)=0, $ so $|(an+b)/n^2|<1$ for all sufficiently large $n.$

Answer (score 0):

After doing some guesswork, I assume you have the following definition:

> $f(n) = O\big(g(n)\big)$ means there are positive constants $c$ and $n_0$, such that $0 \le f(n) \le cg(n)$ for all $n \le n_0$.

(Note that the formal definition of this is slightly different outside of the world of algorithms.)

Anyway to prove that you indeed have $f(n)=O(n^2)$ you must find $c$ and $n_0$
so that $0\le f(n)\le cn^2$ for all $n\ge n_0$.
If you plug in $f(n)$ you get
$0\le an+b \le cn^2$.
Let's verify that the values suggested by the book work.

First take a look at $0\le an+b$. Assuming that $a > 0$,
you can rewrite it as $-\frac ba\le n$.
From this you deduce that $n_0$ must be greater than $-\frac ba$.

Now take $c=a+\lvert b\rvert$, let's have a look at the other inequality:
when do we have $an+b\le cn^2$?
Because the book suggested $n_0=\max\{1; -\frac ba\}$ just take a look at what happens if you assume $n\ge 1$:
$$
cn^2\ge cn=an+\lvert b\rvert n\ge an+\lvert b\rvert\ge an+b
$$

To conclude, if you take the suggested values for $c$ and $n_0$, we've just checked that everything works.